# Snowflake - referring to column groups by a custom name

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say I have

```
CREATE TABLE "test-table" (
  "field1" TEXT,
  "field2" TEXT,
  "field3" TEXT,
  ...
  "field60" TEXT)
```

and I want to insert 30 fields from another table, and 30 fields from another.

I would do this running

```
insert into "test-table"(field1,...,field30)
  select
    field1,field2,...,field30
  from "another-table"
```

In both situations I've used the same long list of fields, can I denote this by a custom object? Like `fieldlist = [field1,field2,...,field30]` and then run commands like `insert into "test-table"(fieldlist)` to tidy up the SQL?

Comment: You can't in native sql  but you can do this with dynamic sql   (query string build using string concatenation and then execute)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Christopher Turnbull, Snowflake follows ANSI SQL 1999 and SQL 2003, and hence it has to be a standard approach to insert data in snowflake. You could achieve this using a stored procedure, however, snowflake does not have any such object which could get this done.

You can submit a feature request to snowflake as your requirement looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor this code by creating a SQL UDF. For example, if you want to insert the number `7` in a table with many columns:

```sql
insert into many_cols
select * from table(to_many_cols(7));
```

The definition of that function would be something like:

```sql
create or replace function to_many_cols(b int) 
returns table(a string, b int, c string, d number, e float)
as $$
select null, b, null, null, null
$$;
```

Which would work on a table like:

```sql
create temp table many_cols (a string, b int, c string, d number, e float);
```